# Converting day field in a df into actual day of week?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, data-science

In my df I have a field called **day** for day and month such as, `2019/07/29` if I want to create another field in the df that states the actual day of week this is such as Sunday or Monday is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: `df['Date'].dt.day_name()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [day_name](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html).

Consider following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2019/07/29','2019/01/20','2019/09/3']
})
```

Gives `df`:

```
    Date
0   2019/07/29
1   2019/01/20
2   2019/09/3
```

Add a column with weekday.

```
df['Weekday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.day_name()
```

Output:

```
         Date   Weekday
0   2019/07/29  Monday
1   2019/01/20  Sunday
2   2019/09/3   Tuesday
```

ideally, you want to convert datetime series to a `Datetime` Object first and then do anything with it.

```
# df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# df['Weekday'] = df['Date'].dt.day_name()
```